# How to programmatically change viewport dimensions (like DevTools can?)

Tags: browser, google-chrome-devtools, userscripts, dimensions, viewport

When viewing a website in Devtools with the Responsive Viewport, you can customize the screen dimensions in pixels. Is this accomplished on the browser end according to CSS/JS rules? <strike>, or are the screen dimensions sent to the website server, which responds appropriately? If it's the latter, how is this info sent - is it part of the useragent, header, HTML tags, something else?</strike>

My goal is to display a website with custom viewport dimensions with something like a UserScript, and *without* using DevTools or physically resizing the browser window.

Comment: On the browser end (aka locally)

Comment: *Why* is that your goal? This might be an XY problem. Do you know about services like BrowserStack?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69292852